# Groups of order $p(p^2+1)/2$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

It seems that when $p>3$ is a prime, then each group of order $p(p^2+1)/2$ is abelian as I checked by Gap for small $p$. Is it true for each $p$?
Thanks for your answers

Comment: When $p=13$, the order is $5\times13\times17$. Now $13\times17\equiv1\pmod5$, which (I think) enables us to conclude that there's a nonabelian group of that order.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: No. The sylow theorems tell us, that there are unique normal subgroups A,B of order 13 and 17. AB is a normal {13,17}-Hall subgroup and any 5-sylow C is a complement. Now any morphism $C\to Aut(AB) = Aut(A)\times Aut(B)\cong C_{12}\times C_{16}$ must be trivial since 5 divides neither 12 nor 16. Therefore the semidirect product $G=(AB)\rtimes C$ is actually a direct product, i.e. $G=A\times B\times C$ is cyclic.

Comment: @GerryMyerson: Note that $5\times 13\times 17$ is coprime to $\phi(5\times 13\times 17)=4\times 12\times 16$.  So by your(!) nice answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/148731/for-which-n-is-there-only-one-group-of-order-n/148738#148738 there is only one group in this situation.  One could also use your answer there to check this -- find $p$ with $n=p(p^2+1)/2$ squarefree but with $n$ not coprime to $\phi(n)$.  The answer with $p=53$ is such an example.

Comment: mathoverflow.net/questions/31553 (answer by R. Chapman) gives a characterization of those integers $n$ for which every finite group of order $n$ is abelian.

Comment: For convenience, let me add a link to the previous comment,  [it's **here**](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/31553/finite-nonabelian-groups-of-odd-order?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: Someone has just voted to close this question as "off topic" - would they care to justify or explain this vote?

Comment: @YemonChoi I voted that this was a better fit at MSE. (The characterisation of orders with all groups abelian is well-known, and easy to google, and it's an easy exercise to find an example after that.)

Comment: @verret fair enough but the question is 5 years old and attracted some informative answers, so I don't see why one should seek to close it now

Comment: The Sylow $p$-subgroup is always normal. By [Schur-Zassenhaus theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_theorem), a group of order $p(p^2+1)/2$ is the semidirect product of $C_p$ and a group of order $(p^2+1)/2$. Since $\gcd((p^2+1)/2,p-1)=1$, the only homomorphism from a group of order $(p^2+1)/2$ to $\operatorname{Aut}(C_p)$ is trivial, so the semidirect product is actually direct. As a result, the question is equivalent to asking about the groups of order $(p^2+1)/2$.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The smallest counterexample I could find is for $p=53$; then $(p^2+1)/2=5\times281$ and the cyclic group of order 281 has an automorphism of order 5, so the corresponding semidirect product will not be abelian.

Answer (score 14):

To make up for my faulty comment, here's a counterexample of a somewhat different type: let $p=193$; then $(p^2+1)/2=5^3\times149$, and there is a nonabelian group of order $5^3$ (as there is of order $q^3$ for every prime $q$), so there's a nonabelian group of order $p(p^2+1)/2$.

Answer (score 12):

In fact, the number of primes $p$ below $x$ for which there are only abelian groups of order $p(p^2+1)/2$ is $o(\pi(x))$.  Thus for almost all primes there will be nonabelian groups of order $p(p^2+1)/2$, despite the initial numerical evidence.

To see this, we will use the criterion provided in the answer of Robin Chapman to [Finite nonabelian groups of odd order](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31553/finite-nonabelian-groups-of-odd-order?lq=1) (which was pointed out by Richard Stanley in the comments above).  One needs $(n,\Phi(n))=1$ if there are only abelian groups of order $n$; here $\Phi(n)$ a variant of the Euler $\phi$-function is multiplicative with $\Phi(p^k) =p^k-1$. Also, if $n$ is cubefree (not divisible by the cube of any prime), then the condition $(n,\Phi(n))=1$ guarantees that the only groups of order $n$ are abelian.

Suppose first that $p \equiv \pm 2 \pmod 5$.  Then $p^2+1$ is a multiple of $5$, and so if $p^2+1$ is divisible by some prime $\ell \equiv 1\pmod{20}$ then we would certainly have that $5$ divides $(n,\Phi(n))$ (writing $n=p(p^2+1)/2$).
Now the density of primes $\ell \equiv 1\pmod{20}$ is $1/8$, and a sieve argument shows that the set of primes $p\le x$ with $p\equiv \pm 2\pmod{5}$ and $p^2+1$ divisible by no such $\ell$ is $O(\pi(x) (\log x)^{-1/4})$; (two residue classes $\pmod \ell$ are forbidden for the prime $p$).  Thus almost all primes $p\equiv \pm 2 \pmod{5}$ have non-abelian groups of order $p(p^2+1)/2$.

Next consider $p\equiv \pm 5 \pmod{13}$ so that $p^2+1 \equiv 0 \pmod{13}$, and repeat the same argument with primes $\ell \equiv 1\pmod{52}$.  And so on.  If there is a small prime $r$ with $r|(p^2+1)$ then $p^2+1$ must avoid primes $\ell \equiv 1\pmod{4r}$ and there are few such primes $p$.  Lastly it could be that $p$ is such that $p^2+1$ does not have any small prime factor $r$; but then the set of such primes $p$ also has small density.

Optimizing this argument one can show that there are at most $O(\pi(x)/\log \log \log x)$ primes for which there are only abelian groups of order $p(p^2+1)/2$. One can also provide a lower bound of this order (but I didn't check all the details here).

Comment: Concerning the second paragraph: we have $(p^k,p^k-1) = 1$, but for $k \geq 3$ there *are* nonabelian groups of order $p^k$ -- how does this fit together with what you write?

Comment: @StefanKohl: Oh right; also $n$ is divisible at most by squares of primes (as in Chapman's answer).  Note that what I wrote was a necessary condition; but I also edited to include the sufficient condition.

Comment: Ah, o.k.. -- I think your bound $O(\pi(x)/\log \log \log x)$ is really nice.

Comment: @StefanKohl: Thanks!  This is essentially the argument of Erdos, Murty & Murty.

Answer (score 5):

For any constant $C \in \mathbb{N}$, there are infinitely many primes $p$
such that there are at least $C$ nonabelian groups of order $p(p^2+1)/2$:

Let $q \equiv 1$ mod $4$ be a prime, and $k \in \mathbb{N}$.
Then the congruence $r^2 \equiv -1$ mod $q^k$ is solvable.
For any solution $r$ and any prime $p \equiv r$ mod $q^k$, the number
$n := p(p^2+1)/2$ is divisible by $q^k$. Now for large enough $k$ there
are more than $C$ nonabelian groups of order $q^k$, and hence also of order $n$.
Since by Dirichlet's Prime Number Theorem there are infinitely many primes
$p \equiv r$ mod $q^k$, the assertion follows.

Some examples: for $k = 3$ and $q = 5$ we obtain the following primes $p < 10000$:

```
193, 307, 443, 557, 1193, 1307, 1693, 2557, 2693, 3307, 3557, 3943,
4057, 4943, 5443, 5557, 5693, 5807, 7057, 7193, 7307, 8443, 8693, 8807
```

(The first is Gerry Myerson's example.)

For $k = 3$ and $q = 13$, we obtain the following examples $p < 1000000$:

```
239, 13421, 34913, 44179, 52489, 52967, 78853, 87641, 96907, 100823, 118399, 131581,
132059, 136453, 144763, 184309, 197969, 206279, 211151, 232643, 263401, 272189, 290243,
329789, 334183, 342971, 368857, 400093, 404009, 408403, 417191, 422063, 439639, 452821,
456737, 461609, 469919, 487973, 496283, 500677, 549011, 562193, 593429, 597823, 619793,
632497, 637369, 646157, 667649, 672043, 672521, 680831, 711589, 712067, 729643, 733559,
751613, 759923, 764317, 777977, 782371, 791159, 804341, 835099, 852197, 857069, 865379,
869773, 883433, 887827, 891743, 901009, 909319, 914191, 927373, 931289, 936161, 966919,
984017, 993283.
```

For $k = 6$ and $q = 5$ (and thus $C = 673$), we obtain the following
examples $p < 1000000$:

```
14557, 16693, 79193, 391693, 672943, 733307, 735443, 829193, 858307, 920807, 952057
```

Comment: That's very nice.  In fact much more is true, and one can show that for almost all primes up to $x$ there will be a non-abelian group of order $p(p^2+1)/2$.  So this may be a candidate for the ``phenomenon of eventual counterexamples."

Comment: @Lucia: How do you conclude that for almost all primes there is such nonabelian group? -- The 2 residue classes (mod $q^3$) for primes $q \equiv 1$ mod 4 don't add up to density 1 -- so probably your argumentation uses cube-free orders $p(p^2+1)/2$?

Comment: Right; one should use instead the criterion provided in the answer linked by Richard Stanley's comment.  The decrease is very slow, as in the case of the Erdos, Murty & Murty result on the orders for which there is exactly one group of order $n$.  I think there'll probably be about $\pi(x)/\log \log \log x$ primes for which there will be only abelian (or even just one cyclic) groups of order $p(p^2+1)/2$.  One can show something like this as an upper bound; but not I think the asymptotic.

Answer (score 3):

It may be worth remarking that since ${\rm gcd}(p-1,\frac{p^{2}+1}{2}) = 1,$ every group of order $\frac{p(p^{2}+1)}{2}$ has a normal subgroup of index $p$ by Burnside's normal $p$-complement theorem. On the other hand, no positive divisor of the odd integer $\frac{p^{2}+1}{2}$ (other than 1) can be congruent to 1 (mod $p$). Hence it is the case that any group of order $\frac{p(p^{2}+1)}{2}$ has a unique Sylow $p$-subgroup, so is a direct product of a group of order $p$ and a group of order $\frac{p{^2}+1}{2}.$ Whether or not the resulting group is Abelian depends only on the structure of the latter group of order $\frac{p^{2}+1}{2},$ which most answers to date have concentrated on anyway. However, it is the case that any such group (of order $\frac{p(p^{2}+1)}{2}$ ) decomposes as a direct product of two smaller non-trivial groups. I don't know if there is a characterization of integers $n$ such that every finite group of order $n$ is decomposable.

Comment: Can we say that this subgroup of order $(p^2+1)/2$ is a characteristic subgroup?

Comment: Yes, we can certainly say that. It is the unique subgroup of that order.