# On the Groups of Order $(p^2+1)/2$

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

A few days ago I asked a question ([Groups of order $p(p^2+1)/2$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/158302)) about a finite group of order $p(p^2+1)/2$ and I got a lot of useful information about it. Thanks for the nice and very helpful answers.  Now I have a question:

> Is it possible that we can conclude that any group of order $(p^2+1)/2$, where $p>13$ and $p\ne 239$ is a prime, has an abelian and normal Sylow subgroup?

For small $p$, i.e., $p<1000$, we can see that most of the time there exists an odd prime $p'$ which is large enough that the subgroup of that order is normal and abelian. Of course this is not always true.

Comment: You could check out $p=239$ when $\frac{p^2+1}{2}=13^4$

Comment: Yes that's right. But we know that by Crescenzo work on the diophantine equation $p^2+1=2q^m$ there is not any other possible case if $p\ne 13$

Comment: So could you edit the question in grey? As it stands, the answer is obviously no.

Comment: A small observation : since the group has odd order, it is soluble. In particular, it has SOME (minimal) abelian normal subgroup. Moreover, by "Groups of Cube-Free Odd Order", by Curran, we may assume that the group is not cube-free.


Anyway, I checked the conjecture up to $p=3000000$. I was only checking that $n=(p^2+1)/2$ was not squarefree and that Sylow's theorem would not force a normal $q$-Sylow subgroup of order at most $q^2$ for some prime $q$. Up to $p=3000000$, the only exceptions are for $p=239$, when we get n=$13^4$ and $p=2905807$ when we get $n=5^4∗13∗61∗97∗137∗641$.

Comment: ADDENDUM:

there are three more candidates for $p$ between 3 and 4 million:
$p=3319597,3456127,3636443$, and then none up to 10 million.

Comment: I think this is as much of a question in number theory as in group theory. I would guess that the conjecture is false, but it could be very hard to find a counterexample. For example, if we had $(p^2+1)/2 = rq^3$, with $q$ prime and $r|(q^2-1)$ then there would be a counterexample of that order.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Theoritically it seems that the answer is No but as Verret checked the numbers it seems that the answer is Yes. But as Derek pointed out  the answer must be NO. Many thanks for your helps

Comment: I didn't say that the answer must be no. But I would be very surprised indeed if it could proved that the answer was yes!

Comment: To try to cook up examples it might help to consider the prime factors of $\frac{p+1}{2} + i\frac{p-1}{2}$ in the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i].$ Here, by prime, I mean an irreducible element of $\mathbb{Z}[i],$ not a rational prime.

Comment: Since we need a normal abelian Sylow subgroup for $G$ for a prime divisor of the order of $G$ can we say that in the above statement the $r$ Sylow subgroup has the stated properties

Answer (score 1):

If for any prime $q$ dividing $\frac12(p^2+1)$ we have $q^3$ divides  $\frac12(p^2+1)$, then the answer is `not'. This is purely number-theoretic question.